SqlDataReader inconsistent speed looping through rows
I have a .NET project in which I run two SQL queries that have more or less the same complexity i.e., same number of NULL checks and INNER joins.
The execution of the first SqlDataReader takes much longer than that of the second one, but this is due to the difference in total number of rows queried. The first SQL query also returns 18 columns, instead of 14 columns in the second SQL query.
The number of rows returned in both SQL datasets is almost the same - approx. 100,000 rows.
When looping through these rows, the first reader is 15 times faster the second reader though:



Action
Elapsed time




Executing 1st reader
00:00:27.0845320


Looping through rows 1st reader
00:00:00.9528895


Executing 2nd reader
00:00:08.4737993


Looping through rows 2nd reader
00:00:14.0965122



The SQL query I use is for retrieving the data in the second reader, and looping through, is:
Using myConn = New SqlConnection(connectionString)
   Dim myCmd = New SqlCommand(sqlCustomerPoint, myConn)
   myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaLevel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _AreaLevel
   myCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@AreaName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = _AreaName
   myCmd.CommandTimeout = 0

   myConn.Open()

   Using myReader As SqlDataReader = myCmd.ExecuteReader
      If myReader.HasRows Then
         Do While myReader.Read()
            'Process the data
            setCustomerPointDetails(myReader)
         Loop
      End If
   End Using
End Using

Even when commenting out the code within the loop (setCustomerPointDetails(myReader)), the loop takes almost the same time.
The SQL query used for the second SqlDataReader is
DECLARE @AreaLevel as CHAR(40) = 'District'
DECLARE @AreaName  as CHAR(40) = 'Rotterdam'

SELECT
    pnt.se_fld2_pointid2,
    se_fld5_nodeid2,
    pipe.se_fld0_id,
    chain.se_fld2_chainid2,
    pnt.se_fld14_coord.STX as se_fld14_coord_X,
    pnt.se_fld14_coord.STY as se_fld14_coord_Y,
    sp.se_fld50_sapid,
    sp.se_fld67_street,
    ISNULL(sp.se_fld71_housenumber, 0) as se_fld71_housenumber,
    sp.se_fld70_city,
FROM Mainserver.history.se_hm2_t106_topologicalpoin as pnt
INNER JOIN Mainserver.history.se_hm2_t82_joint as j
    ON j.se_fld33_rwoid2 = pnt.se_fld8_rwoid2
INNER JOIN VSDWHP.history.se_hm2_t96_servicepoint as sp
    ON j.se_fld0_id = sp.se_fld61_jointid
INNER JOIN Mainserver.history.se_hm2_t103_topologicalchai as chain
    ON (pnt.se_fld5_nodeid2 = chain.se_fld12_lastnodeid2)
INNER JOIN Mainserver.history.se_hm2_t85_mainsection as pipe
    ON chain.se_fld15_rwoid2 = pipe.se_fld53_rwoid2
INNER JOIN 
    (
    SELECT * 
    FROM Mainserver.Area
    WHERE name = @AreaName and level = @AreaLevel 
        and Tot > DATEFROMPARTS(2098,1,1)
    ) as area
    ON pnt.se_fld14_coord.STIntersects(area.Shape) = 1
WHERE
    pnt.se_history_validto > DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1)
    and j.se_history_validto > DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1)
    and sp.se_history_validto > DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1)
    and chain.se_history_validto > DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1)
    and pipe.se_history_validto > DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1)
    and sp.se_fld76_sapobjectstatus = 'In bedrijf'
    and se_fld10_appcode = 5

Any thought to what might cause these differences, is much appreciated.
UPDATE: In SSMS, I noticed that results/rows were already partly shown while the query was still running on the server. When I added an ORDER BY se_fld5_nodeid2, the query is first finished and only then the results are shown. In my application, this resulted in longer execution time on the server and (very) fast looping through the rows.
Conclusion: while looping through the rows, the SQL query was still being executed?

Did you run the queries on the database server and check respective execution times? Perhaps the first query has an execution plan that can utilize indexes and the second doesn't?

I agree with above comment. Is there any sort by on the 2nd example? Also, is there some binary "blob" or varchar(max) column on the 2nd example? Remember, a blob (varbinary) or varchar(max) is placed outside of the main table (and linked to the main table), and hence the time to pull and retrieve these "blob" type columns is VERY expensive. Hence, if you don't need that blob type column, then remove that column from the query if such columns are not being used. so this is either indexing, or that the 2nd table has some blob type columns which are VERY expensive to retrieve in such queries.

Presumably this is nothing to do with SqlClient, and it actually due to different execution plans. Please share them via https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan, please also show relevant tables and indexes. Most likely the 1st query uses blocking operators such as Sort and Hash, whereas the 2nd is non-blocking so you get a streaming output. Side note: you don't need to do If myReader.HasRows Then the Do loop already does that.

With regards to the above comment about HasRows you only need to test that property if you explicitly want to do something different in the case where there's no records, e.g. display a message to the user to that effect. Otherwise, calling Read once or in a loop has the same effect.

Whenever you have an issue with SQL Server queries, you should be using the SQL Server tools to test and debug first, before posting here. That means running the query in SSMS, using SQL Profiler, etc.

Thanks for the tip on removing the check HasRows. Also, see edit for the query used in the 2nd SqlDataReader

I think the difference is if there are some blocking operators in the query plan (ie. early sort), which lead to either rows being streamed early or if they have to wait until some operators are done. In the end, i guess it shouldn't matter, the query will still take what it takes. You can run your query from management studio Live mode and see how rows are streamed for both cases

It seems that your use of DATEFROMPARTS(9999, 1, 1) in the rows is causing your SQL plan to use Row-by-row processing. This can occur when there are data type mismatches that require casting or when a function needs to be executed during a comparison.
As you always have the same store the value in a variable and then use the variable.
If you execute it in SSMS and you look at the execution plan you are likely to see it mention it

Are you sure about that? Can you create a fiddle that demonstrates it?

The inner join on the area (with the DATEFROMPARTS bit) is the same in the first SqlDataReader, and there the performance is great; of looping through the rows. I will test the query in SSMS soon!
